# Not able to set text on Textview from fragment class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am not able to set the text from **Homefragment.java**

Currently I have below **xml** files:

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

     <include
        android:id="@+id/ftr"
        layout="@layout/tab" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
            </LinearLayout>
```

Now **tab.xml**

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </TableRow>
```

Now class files:

**activity_main.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        initUI();

    }

    private void initUI() {

     fragment = new HomeFragment();
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private TextView txt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);

        context = getActivity();
        initUI(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void initUI(View view) {




    txt = (TextView)view.findViewbyid(R.id.txt1);

         txt.setText("hello. test");
}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

....
</RelativeLayout
```

**Error log:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.xx.ew.fragment.HomeFragment.initUI(HomeFragment.java:112)
            at com.xx.ew.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:99)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1174)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5356)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now the issue is When I am trying to set text of **Textview** of **tab.xml** in **homefragment** class then it is not set the text and force close the app.

How can set the text of **textview(txt1)** of **tab.xml** from **homefragment.java** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No. its not same question.

Answer (score 0):

> Changed my answer

Call your fragment as follows in initUI() method of activity:-

```
private void initUI() {
  fragment = new HomeFragment();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tab_bar, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }
```

In Fragment change only one line which is in **createView** method

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, container,
                false);
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com. com.xx.ew.fragment.HomeFragment.initUI(HomeFragment.java:107)
            at  com.xx.ew.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:99)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)`

Comment: i have already have  ` fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);` which is LinearLayout in that xml.

Comment: And Have you changed the line in your **HomeFragemnt** which i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: if i change the rootView then what happens to old layout xml which is currently defined in my code.

Comment: Inflating rootview in fragment only replace rootview layout the other views wont get affected by it.

Comment: ok so i have to change the `initUI()` of activity_main.java or have to change in Homefragment.java file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88245/discussion-between-deepak-and-clairvoyant).

Comment: Its the only code you have posted here for `fragment` or are you doing something else also in **onCreateView()** method.

Comment: can we discuss this in chat ? if possible then. please.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private Context context;

private TextView txt;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
            false);

    context = getActivity();
    initUI(rootView);

    return rootView;
}

private void initUI(View view) {
    txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    txt.setText("hello. test");
}
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
    android:id="@+id/ftr"
    layout="@layout/tab" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:
Make rootView a global variable. And then override the onStart method and call initUI from there.